# CouchDB crashes when bound to public ip

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ip, couchdb

I have a CouchDB server running on a Amazon EC2 instance, when I start it bound to

```
127.0.0.1
```

it works just fine, but when

```
bind_address = my.public.ip
```

it crashes on start with the error

```
Failure to start Mochiweb: eaddrnotavail
```

This error occurs when the address is invalid, though multiple checks verify that it is in fact valid, and when

```
bind_address = 0.0.0.0
```

it works just fine.

Comment: I'll assume that "multiple checks" didn't include running `ifconfig`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot why would you assume that? Because it did

Comment: I made that assumption because have never seen an EC2 instance that actually has its public IP bound to an interface... typically the outside public IP is natted to a private internal IP from the EC2 private pool (classic) or your private pool (VPC).  I'm unaware of any way to assign a.public IP to an interface in EC2 unless you're tunneling non-AWS-provided public IPs frim somewhere (which would be quite unusual, I would think).

Answer (score 0):

eaddrnotavail means that the port is not available,you have to edit your /etc/couchdb/couch.ini file and change the port setting to an available port.